# Likes and comments in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I'm creating an app where i have following classes at the moment User, Items and Comments.

User:
displayName : string

Items:
Like : Relation

Comments: 
text: string
item: pointer

what i want is to show a CollectionView of all items with comments count and like count (and check if the current user has liked the image).

I'm wondering if this is the best solution for this, since i've read that it might be better to have an activity class which handle both the likes and the comments like in the Anypic tutorial app.

so what is the best class architecture for creating such a view?

[image]

Comment: Nice giving minus without writing a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with structure suggested at [Anypic](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic)
You app looks very simple to [Anypic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anypic/id539741538?ls=1&mt=8), just reuse what Parse did, they did it smart.
Take theirs code implementation and reuse smart solution.

**Model**
 1. User - Basic user info (name, email, id, etc)
 2. Item - Your items displayed in collection. (photo, owned, name, etc)
 3. Activity - (from, to, type, content) - likes, comments

In the other hand making separate model for "Like" and "Comment" would separate those 2 entities.
In General while programming you should create separate classes and entities.

Comment: So it would be okay to make 2 entity classes, one for like and one for comment, so we will have less data in each class, and a better overview, and probably no wasting space as we could have if we combined the two classes as one?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And I like this approach as well